# Form field "showon" with multiple fields

Tags: joomla-3.x, fields, showon

I have 3 fields defined in my XML file like so:

```
<field name="field1" type="radio" label="Field 1" class="btn-group" default="1">
    <option value="1">JYES</option>
    <option value="0">JNO</option>
</field>

<field name="field2" type="radio" label="Field 2" class="btn-group" default="1">
    <option value="1">JYES</option>
    <option value="0">JNO</option>
</field>

<field name="field3" type="radio" label="Field 3" class="btn-group" default="1">
    <option value="1">JYES</option>
    <option value="0">JNO</option>
</field>
```

Now what I'd like to do is only show `field3` **if** `field1` **and** `field2` are set to `1`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can chain the attribute values of `showon`, using `[AND]`, like so:

```
showon="field1:1[AND]field2:1"
```

Adding more fields to the chain is also allowed.

On a side note, you can use an `[OR]` clause in the chain too, adding more complexity, for example:

```
showon="field1:1[AND]field2:1[OR]fieldX:1"
```

---

#### Update for Joomla 3.7:

As of Joomla 3.7, you will be able to to use the `!` operator (not equal to):

```
showon="field1!:1"
```

This means, if `field1` does **not** equal **1**

Comment: Is there a not equal to option for showon?

Comment: @CoalaWeb - That's what it's already doing. `field1:1` means `field1 == 1`

Comment: I'm looking for a != option for large/dynamic select lists that only have one option that would hide another form field rather than a large comma separated list. From my research it doesn't look like this exist I might look into a pull request, Cheers.

Comment: can you use `!empty` or `!:*` ?

Comment: Apparently you can use `showon="foo!:"` I am yet to test. See here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/form-field-showonempty

Comment: @Lodder do you know if the `!` not empty works on text fields?  It's not working on my module.

Comment: @Eoin - I don't think you can use `!empty`. I haven't tested this on inputs/textareas but perhaps there's an alternative. Only thing I can think of would be a custom form field.

Comment: Can you do an `[AND]` `[OR]`?  I want to show either one field or the other depending on whether the opposite is empty.  However if both are empty as is the starting case they will disappear.  Is there a way to do `showon="field!!: [OR] field1!:[AND]field2!;"`

Comment: You cannot do the above

Comment: Is it possible to set a condition with a string contains statement?