# Form Field showon:"empty

Tags: form-fields-types, showon

Using this documentation https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field I have developed a plugin and used the `showon` attribute within the XML (head to the bottom of that page).

Whilst is shows me I can use

`showon="foo:1[AND]bar:1"` and

`showon="foo:1[OR]bar:1"`

I would like to showon based on whether a text field is not empty.  Is this a possibility or will I require JS?

I have also heard you can do `showon="field1!:1"` and `showon=field!"`

Here's my code which shows both fields.

```
<field
        name="telephone"
        type="text"
        label="MOD_HEADER_CONTACT_TELEPHONE_LABEL"
        description="MOD_HEADER_CONTACT_TELEPHONE_DESC"
        default=""
        class=""
/>
<field
        name="countrycode"
        type="text"
        label="MOD_HEADER_CONTACT_COUNTRY_CODE_LABEL"
        description="MOD_HEADER_CONTACT_COUNTRY_CODE_DESC"
        default=""
        class=""
        required="required"
        showon="telephone!:"
/>
```

Comment: Hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do this:

```
showon="foo!:"
```

Comment: I tried this and the field shows from the beginning.  Is this definitely correct?

Comment: Yes i tried it.

Comment: What is the input type?

Comment: Both text, maybe I should do a code example

Comment: I am sure that it works with text.

Comment: We need to invent a Joomla! fiddle!

Comment: I added a code example maybe you can see an error?

Comment: No any error for me, it works normally, what is your joomla version? mine is 3.7.2

Comment: Using exactly the same code?  And the text area disappears?  I have the same version.  What stupidity could I be doing here.  I'll strip it back to the bone like my example and then try it from there.  Must be user error.. THANK YOU for taking a look, I very much appreciate your time.

Comment: Yeah the same code and it works for me, hahaha i understand you the same version and different result :/, thank you and you are welcome

Comment: I revisited this on a new module and it works.  Thanks for answering