# How to use the showon attribute with multiple conditions?

Tags: joomla-3.x, form-fields-types, xml, showon, conditional-statements

In a Joomla 3.9.3 module, I'm trying, with no luck, to show/hide a field with showon by checking the values on other three fields

My XML:

```
<field
    name="foo"
    type="text"
/>
<field
    name="bar"
    type="text"
/>
<field
     name="fooimg"
    type="media"
    showon="foo!:[OR]bar!:"
/>
<field
    name="baz"
    type="radio"
    class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
    showon="foo!:[OR]bar!:[AND]fooimg!:"
    default=""
    >
    <option value="bazval">JYES</option>
    <option value="">JNO</option>
</field>
```

With: `showon="foo!:[OR]bar!:[AND]fooimg!:"` on baz field I expect that baz is shown when (foo or bar has a value) and fooimg has a value too.

But the results are:

```
    foo = true 
    bar = false
    fooimage = true
    baz is NOT SHOWED (should be showed)

    foo = false
    bar = true
    fooimage = true
    baz IS SHOWED (as aspected)
```

With fooimage or foo and bar set to False it work as expected.

I also tried: `"fooimg!:[AND]foo!:[OR]bar!:"`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Relevant comment from Eoin: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17681/form-field-showon-with-multiple-fields#comment26931_17682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fully sure if this can help you, but since the `fooimg` field is only shown when either `foo` or `bar` **is true**, then in `baz` field you do not have to check that again, so it would be enough just to check if `fooimg` field is **true** or not, thus:

```
<field
    name="baz"
    type="radio"
    class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
    showon="fooimg!:"
    default=""
    >
    <option value="bazval">JYES</option>
    <option value="">JNO</option>
</field>
```

This `baz` field will only be shown if the `foo` **or** `bar` is not empty **and** `fooimg` is not empty. So you actually get the same result simply (that you actually wanted to get).

Comment: Thanks @zollie, in effect at first I designed the module like this,  but its not correct, in case of the data update, there is a possibility that the values in "foo"/"bar" will be deleted, in this case,  "baz" stay visible without the possibility to change fooimg, to hide baz, because its hidden.

Comment: @Znort - in FormHelper class I do not really see the possibility to chain conditions like you tried. It looks like that the method (`parseShowOnConditions()`) only consider 1 OR or 1 AND as condition.

Comment: You right @zollie, it seems that the showon is still not well implemented, also with the combo fields has some issues. Many Thanks anyway!